# Server randomly inaccessible in certain areas

Tags: centos7, whm

I am running a WHM/Cpanel server, CentOS 7.63. Over the last few days, all sites on the server have become inaccessible in some areas. I have identified New York, San Hose and Vancouver using various "site speed" tests. A reboot fixes the problem but it returns several hours later. At first, I thought it may be CSF related but that has been uninstalled (temporarily) and the issue persists. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an apache problem. If CSF is disabled so all access is permitted to the server and the websites hosted on it then most probably apache is not processing the incoming requests. Server reboot is not necessary. You can just restart the apache service:

`/etc/init.d/httpd restart (CentOS 6.x)`

`systemctl restart httpd (CentOS 7.x)`

That should fix the service so it's not necessary to restart the server.

In order to investigate what leads to the apache crash or malfunction (if that's the case) you will have to check the apache logs and eventually cpanel logs

for apache logs check: `/usr/local/apache/logs/`

for cpanel logs check: `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/`

Sorry I can't help you more than this but the informations you have provided are limited so it's pretty hard to guess

Comment: Thanks for the response. This isn't the cause of the problem either. After taking your advice, I also tried restarting all the systems available for restart inside the WHM interface; no luck. I realise it must be one system in particular but, so far, only a full reboot fixes the issue

Comment: If you could provide more details about the exact error message or whatever is shown in the browser when "the sites become unavailable" then it would be easier to provide a proper answer.

Comment: Clients have told me that their browser just times out.

Comment: Yeah well that could be due to a lot of reasons. Could be a temporary block because of the server's firewall if you have one. Do you use any WAF or fail2ban or any other similar tools?

Comment: We use CSF and have already disabled it and LFD for testing; changed nothing. Other than that only CpHulk.

Comment: I don't think cphulkd is the issue here. Could be an apache issue or maybe a DNS related one